# Cannot compile .cs file which call another class member or using other namespace than "System"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, namespaces, coreclr

I just begin a test with CoreCRL. I could compile and run the HelloWorld.cs example. But when I add some extra function to make it more really, this is my code:

```
using System;

namespace BenchMark
{
    class Program
    {
        /*******************************************************************************/
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BenchMark.exe C# runned");
                string[] param = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
                var benchMarkType = param[1];
                switch (benchMarkType)
                {
                    case "alg":
                        PhepToanDaiSo p = new PhepToanDaiSo();
                        p.callAlg(param);
                        break;
                    case "method":
                        ThuatToanBiz.callMethod(param);
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        /*************************************************/
    }
}
```

All the class and calling is valid, I can run this program successfully. But when I try to compile it use CoreCLR, with syntax:

```
E:\Learning\Viegrid\Native\SVN\trunk\BenchMark\BenchMark>csc /nostdlib /noconfig /r:packages\System.Runtime.4.0.20-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Runtime.dll /r:packages\System.Console.4.0.0-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Console.dll /out:runtime\BenchMark.exe Program.cs
```

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0 for C# 5 Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I got the error:

```
Program.cs(13,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Environment' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are
        you missing an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(18,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PhepToanDaiSo' could not be found (are you missing a using
        directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(18,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PhepToanDaiSo' could not be found (are you missing a using
        directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(22,25): error CS0103: The name 'ThuatToanBiz' does not exist in the current context
```

I did something wrong? Or coreclr is only can't work with any namespace except "System"?

Comment: Why are you using `/nostdlib`?

Comment: I just follow the tutorial at their official page https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/windows-instructions.md, helloworld example worked that way too.